# Speech Recognition in C# with specific command

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, speech, speech-synthesis

I was developed a application that can only recognize some word. I've several questions.

1)Can I able to develop something like

```
if(command == Browser)
{
    //open default browser
}
```

2) If Yes, how can Recognize System understand the custom word??

Any code sample or tutorial will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with Microsoft Speech API System.Speech.Recognition.

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361683.aspx) article

Comment: Yes, I know that. Already, I developed an application with that. How about the custom word??

Comment: what do you mean by custom words? You can add words as Choice in grammar builder.